# does a 3-D printed plastic electric guitar, in comparison to a normal hardwood one, have more inferior tone, or other bad qualities?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, guitar-effects, acoustics

I've started looking into 3-D designed musical instruments (yes that's apparently a thing now) and wanted to know if it's a good direction, if I want to customize my own electric guitar

Comment: There is very little, if any, difference in sound. The 3D-printed guitars I've seen and played have all been assembled around a block of wood that holds the bridge and pickups, essentialy making it no different from a "regular" electric guitar. What brand/maker have you been lookin at?

Comment: You may find http://www.odd.org.nz/construction.html to be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

The critical parts of the guitar for sustain and tone are all between the nut and the bridge, so if you add any shaped pieces on anywhere else they will not make audible differences.

On the very high end guitars, the "horns" and other bits are designed to resonate at specific frequencies so they will have an effect on sound, but for most guitars any effect from these is not going to be audible over the impact of wood or glue choice, electrics, pickups etc.

For some of the electric guitars I have made I have changed the shape over time by hacksawing off various bits; making sure I didn't touch that critical core. There was no change I could hear.